# C# GridView Cell - hyperlink

Tags: c#, gridview

I have this code to get data from my database to a Gridview:

```
public void mainSelect(DataGridView gvMain)
        {
            string sSQL = " SELECT" +
                "      tbMain.id, tbBrand.name AS brand, tbModel.name AS model, tbMain.name, tbType.name AS type, tbClub.name AS club, tbMain.serial, tbMain.porder, tbMain.link, tbUser.name AS lastEditBy, tbMain.lastEditDate" +
                          "  FROM" +
                          "      tbMain, tbBrand, tbModel, tbType, tbClub, tbUser" +
                          " WHERE" +
                          "     tbBrand.id = tbMain.brand" +
                          " AND" +
                          "     tbModel.id = tbMain.model" +
                          " AND" +
                          "     tbType.id = tbMain.type" +
                          " AND" +
                          "     tbClub.id = tbMain.club" +
                          " AND" +
                          "     tbUser.id = tbMain.lastEditBy" +
                          " ORDER BY " +
                          "     club ASC";

            sqlConnect connect = new sqlConnect();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = connect.getBD(sSQL);

            gvMain.DataSource = dt;
            gvMain.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
            gvMain.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Brand";
            gvMain.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Model";
            gvMain.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Computer Name";
            gvMain.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Type";
            gvMain.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Site";
            gvMain.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Serial Number";
            gvMain.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Purchase Order";
            gvMain.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Invoice Link";
            gvMain.Columns[9].HeaderText = "Last Edit By";
            gvMain.Columns[10].HeaderText = "Last Edit Date";
```

It work fine, what I need now is to set the 8th column (invoice link) to be a link field so I can click and open it.

how can I accomplish this ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using `DataGridViewLinkColumn`

```
DataGridViewLinkColumn link = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
link.DataPropertyName = "InvoiceLink";
link.Name = "Invoice Link";       
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(link);
```

add it to your grid, after binding your grid
you might need to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false

Comment: doesn't work. adds a collumn but with no data and not linkable :(

Answer (score 0):

Use templatefields in Gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("LeadID") + Request.QueryString("type") %>'
                            Text=""></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```